# valueCallback in custom form element is not invoking itself?

Tags: forms, 8

I am creating a custom form element in my custom module. Everything is working fine except the valueCallback function is not invoking itself. I have done it in following way :

Name space

```
namespace Drupal\custom_element\Element;
```

getInfo and valueCallback Method:

```
public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#process' => [
        [$class, 'processCheckboxes'],
      ],
      '#theme' => 'custom_theme',
      '#value_callback' => ['valueCallback'], // Try with and without #value_callback key
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function valueCallback(&$element, $input, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dsm('in valuecallback');
  }
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

**Related Link :** https://www.drupal.org/node/2320115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't invoke itself when `#value` is already set to element. I didn't notice that I set it in theme function. After removing `#value` key from `$element` array it is working fine.